# [Flutter]: notifyListeners not working from other screens or popups

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-packages

I am using the provider libarary for my state management and everything works fine up until this point. However, I have noticed that when calling `notifyListeners` from another screen (or a popup like `showModalBottomSheet`) my UI will not be notified.

The method I am using in the `provider` looks something like this and adds an item to a ListView:

```
void addEntry(http.Response response) {
  Group group = Group.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  groups.add(group);
  notifyListeners();
}
```

As for the UI the entire Screen is wrapped in a `Consumer`. Calling this method from a button in the screen works fine and the list is updated. Calling this method from a popup created with `showModalBottomSheet` does not update the UI.

How do I ensure the UI is notified of the changes?

---

Update #1:

I have a button that calls `showModalBottomSheet` like this:

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  ...
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
      child: AddWidget(model: Provider.of<GroupsProvider>(context)),
    );
  },
);
```

So it creates a popup with a separate widget. That separate widget in turn does this when another button is pressed:

```
widget.model.createGroup(name, icon);
```

This method eventually calls `addEntry`. As I said this works perfectly fine without a popup but does not work at all in the popup :/

Comment: please add all the codes that are involved. let's do a quick review

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question.

Comment: this is what I think. I think the showModalBottomSheet<Button in the popup> fires a  context pop. that pop off the BottomSheet immediately instead of popping off itself.

Comment: try to refactor your code considering  this possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pop-ups like bottomsheets are most likely opened from the root navigator and hence provides a different context and if your provider is not created above the root Navigator i.e above the MaterialApp, it will cause this issue.
The `context` that is coming from the `builder` of the `showModalBottomSheet` is not where your Provider is created.
There are 2 solutions I can think of:

1. Just before calling the `showModalBottomSheet` , you can create a reference to the Provider and then pass that to the AddWidget.

```
var provider = Provider.of<GroupsProvider>(context, listen:false);

showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  ...
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
      child: AddWidget(model: provider),
    );
  },
);
```

2. Use the `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` and wrap the widget in the builder with it.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  ...
  context: context,
  builder: (_) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Provider.of<GroupsProvider>(context, listen:false),
         builder: (context, _) =>
                Padding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
      child: AddWidget(model: Provider.of<GroupsProvider>(context)),
    );
       );
  },
);
```

(2) ensures that the widget tree below it will have access to the same Provider instance. For new screens, you can do :

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(...),
   ),
);
```

Looking at the widget inspector in debug mode will help you understand better

Comment: Hmm it does seem to be related to the context but those two approaches did not fix it :(

Comment: hmm, atleast the first approach should have worked. I edited the first to `listen:false`. You mentioned you are doing a similar call in a separate button on the same screen, is the context used in that button the same as the one used before the `showModalBottomSheet` ?  Or do you have any errors ?

Comment: Okay, the first approach actually works from a button in the same screen (even with a  `modalBottomSheet` now). The problem: I was calling the `modalBottomSheet` from a `FloatingActionButton` that is embedded into the root screen. The screen in question is a child in a `bottomNavigation`. Any ideas how I could solve this? Maybe add some callbacks to the child screen?

Comment: not work for me